# why isn't my dynamic button disabled with knockoutjs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I'm not sure why my dynamic button not disabled using knockoutjs?

Original working dynamic html and knockoutjs: [Link1](http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/FCN5p/)
Work in progress: [Link2](http://jsfiddle.net/FCN5p/568/)

```
var viewModel = {
    first: ko.observable("Bob"),
    last: ko.observable("Smith"),
    isEnabled: ko.observable("disabled")
};

viewModel.fullName = ko.dependentObservable(function() {
    return this.first() + " " + this.last();
}, viewModel);

function addDynamicContent() {
    $("#main").append("<div id='dynamic' data-bind='text: fullName'></div><input id='Button1' type='button' value='Hello World' data-bind='disabled=isEnabled' />");

    ko.applyBindings(viewModel, $("#dynamic")[0]);
}

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your data bind syntax for the disable binding is incorrect in your appended HTML, and your reapplication of bindings isn't quite correct.

**Change your enabled/disabled observable to use a boolean value**

```
isEnabled: ko.observable("disabled")
```

should be:

```
isEnabled: ko.observable(true)
```

**Correct the disable data bind syntax in your appended markup**

```
$("#main").append("<div id='dynamic' data-bind='text: fullName'></div><input id='Button1' type='button' value='Hello World' data-bind='disabled=isEnabled' />");
```

should be:

```
$("#main").append("<div id='dynamic' data-bind='text: fullName'></div><input id='Button1' type='button' value='Hello World' data-bind='disable: isEnabled' />");
```

**Change your binding update to re-bind the whole viewmodel**

```
ko.applyBindings(viewModel, $("#dynamic")[0]);
```

should be:

```
ko.cleanNode($("#main")[0]);
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

[Updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FCN5p/571/).

This will get your example functional, however if you are working with dynamic content, I strongly recommend using some additional bindings instead of appending HTML and redoing your bindings every time. Have a look at [Observable arrays](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html), the [template binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html), and [working with collections](http://knockoutjs.com/examples/collections.html).

I threw together another [JS Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/h5bsbxgm/4/) that shows another approach to dynamic content and bindings using the bindings mentioned above.

Comment: Thanks so much, for the extra insight!